# What is a "page" in the SQLite documentation?

Tags: sqlite

I'm currently reading the SQLite documentation related to atomic commits and transaction stuff.
http://sqlite.org/wal.html

All over the place, they're talking about "pages". Obviously this refers to a specific space in memory/on disk, but what exactly is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the fundamental unit of space allocation used by the database. You can set it via a [suitable pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size) but I've never needed to do that.